# Cannot remove file that I am the owner of

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using both Cygwin and WSL (Ubuntu) on Windows. I ran a command that created a file in Cygwin, and then when I view the same file in WSL, it says that I own it and the directory containing it, and that I have all permissions to it. However, when I try to delete it, I get permission denied

```
> sudo rm file1.txt
rm: cannot remove 'file1.txt': Permission denied
> whoami
jeff
> ls -la
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 jeff jeff 512 Dec  1 14:55 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 jeff jeff 512 Dec  1 14:55 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 0 jeff jeff 999 Dec  1 14:40 file1.txt
> cd ..
> ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 jeff jeff 512 Dec  1 14:55 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 jeff jeff 512 Dec  1 14:55 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 jeff jeff 512 Dec  1 14:55 folder1
```

I have tried running `rm` with and without sudo, removing the containing folder, and disowning then owning the file and parent folder again, what else can I try, assuming that using Cygwin or Windows to remove the file is not an option?

Comment: @Ramhound so what can I do? as far as I can tell, WSL is telling me that I already have all the permissions I need

Comment: Cygwin is not actually Linux. Its simply a POSIX compatible environment while WSL is actually Linux. Where exactly is this file? Only Windows understands the files contained within the WSL instance.

Comment: @Ramhound It's near the WSL home directory, equivalent to C:/wsl/rootfs/home/test/folder1/file1.txt and ~/test/folder1/file.txt

Comment: and where are you attempting to access them from within Cygwin, since that directory, does not exist outside of WSL. I wanted specifics

Comment: I can access it in Cygwin through /cygdrive/c/wsl/rootfs/home/test/folder1/file1.txt

Comment: What is the exact location within Windows? Are you sure it’s the same file?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that is it the same file, because I was in a parent folder in Cygwin when the file was created, it didn't exist in WSL before, and now it does

Comment: Your going to need to provide more details in the body of your question.

Comment: Okay, what other details do you need?

Comment: What is the exact location within Windows? For instance I can’t tell if *cygdrive/c/wsl/rootfs/home/test/folder1/file1.txt* is a virtual directory within Cygwin or not

Comment: I stated in an above comment, the exact location within Windows is C:/wsl/rootfs/home/test/folder1/file1.txt

Comment: Except that cannot be the file path. It should be something like “\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04”, we are talking about WSL2, right? The part after wsl$ depends on the name of the instance

Comment: I don't think that it's WSL2

Comment: Check if the file is immutable by running `lsattr` like this: `lsattr file1.txt`. The file listing for an immutable file should look something like this: `----i-----------`. If it has the immutable setting then run `sudo chattr -I file1.txt` and then you should be able to remove it. More details [here](https://www.tecmint.com/chattr-command-examples/).

Comment: @Jeffmagma - Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

*The information in the comments shows a potentially major problem.  For starters, please remember to edit your question with the information you provided in the comments.  That's critical information to anyone understanding your issue that should be a part of the question, rather than the comments. (Feel free to edit this answer to remove the italicized area once the question has been updated).*

*Now on to the likely problem ...*

Danger! Danger! As @Jeffmagma said in the comments, this doesn't look like WSL2.  Since the file is exposed in `C:\wsl\rootfs` (visible to Cygwin at `/cygdrive/c/wsl/rootfs`), that looks to be a WSL1 filesystem rather than
a WSL2 virtual drive (which would show up as an `ext4.vhdx`).

And that falls into [this Microsoft Warning](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/):

> There is one hard-and-fast rule when it comes to WSL on Windows:
>
> DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, access, create, and/or modify Linux files inside of your `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.
>
> Creating/changing Linux files in your Appdata folder from Windows will likely result in data corruption and/or damage your Linux environment requiring you to uninstall & reinstall your distro!

... which is actually a bit poorly worded.  It references "AppData", but that's the *default* location for WSL installations.

In this case, it looks like you've created a WSL1 instance at `C:\WSL`.  There's nothing at all wrong with that, but Microsoft's warning still applies.  Attempting to create, update, or delete a file using a Windows application (e.g. Cygwin) in that path is almost certain to cause issues.

And unfortunately it sounds like it may very well have caused filesystem corruption in this case.

To attempt recovery, I would try:

- Another `wsl --export` of this WSL1 instance
- Then `wsl --import` it into a new instance.  I'm assuming you are familiar with this process since it's likely what you used to create the instance at `C:\wsl\` in the first place.  I would add `--version 2` to the end of the `--import` command, personally.
- See if (a) the problem-file exists in the new instance (it may be culled by the `export`, actually), and (b) if it does exist, see if you can delete it.

Comment: I don't know my root cause, and wouldn't recommend, but I ended up here with a similar issue on a WSL1 distro, and the only way I could delete it WAS in the windows rootfs. Deleting it there removed it from WSL. This was preventing a wsl --export